# Would this specific type of situation be considered an XSS vulnerability?

Tags: security, xss

I am new to learning about web security. Recentlty, I found a website which has a search bar and the search bar sends a GraphQL query for each input change. If it does not find something, it will return with the exact search query and display 'No results found ...", where '...' is the search query.

If I put the search with a script tag that alerts something and some other specific words, it will return the query and run it on the browser and the alert shows. The thing is, I am not really sure how GraphQL works. The URL of the webpage does not change. I can also see that a GraphQL query was made and it returned the search query (through Chrome Dev Tools Network tab).

Would this specific situation be considered an XSS vulnerability?

Comment: If you are attacking yourself in your own browser, no. If the server saves it and feeds to another user, yes.

Comment: @GSerg Yeah it is only done on my browser, so I guess it's not a vulnerability then, thanks!

Comment: It *is* xss still, self xss might be lower risk but still a vulnerability. And there might also be a way to pass it to another user. It's definitely something that would be included in a pentest report.